# How to order data on Inner Join MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a case to create podcast playlist based on category sorts. For example, I want to join podcast data and category data based on the table below.

```
> SELECT * FROM category_sorts;

+----+-------------+------+
| id | category_id | sort |
+----+-------------+------+
|  1 |           2 |    1 |
|  2 |           1 |    2 |
|  3 |           1 |    3 |
|  4 |           2 |    4 |
+----+-------------+------+
```

Column `category_id` related to categories table.

```
> SELECT * FROM categories;

+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | title        | status    |
+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | Saga         | published |
|  2 | Asia Calling | published |
+----+--------------+-----------+
```

And here some sample data from `podcasts` table with a related category.

```
> SELECT * FROM podcasts;

+----+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+
| id | category_id | title                  | published_at        |
+----+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 | Sejarah Rumah Dengklok | 2018-05-01 22:40:47 |
|  3 |           2 | Berita Asia!           | 2018-05-01 22:52:15 |
|  4 |           2 | Asia Later!            | 2018-05-01 23:47:13 |
|  5 |           1 | Saga terbaru           | 2018-05-02 00:06:32 |
+----+-------------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

Using the provided query below, I got duplicate podcasts in the same category sorts.

```
SELECT
        p.id, p.title AS podcast_title, p.published_at, 
        c.title AS category_title,
        cs.sort
    FROM podcasts as p
    INNER JOIN categories as c ON c.id = p.category_id
    INNER JOIN category_sorts AS cs on cs.category_id = c.id
    GROUP BY cs.sort
    ORDER BY cs.sort ASC, p.published_at DESC
```

Results:

```
+----+------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------+
| id | podcast_title          | published_at        | category_title | sort |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------+
|  3 | Berita Asia!           | 2018-05-01 22:52:15 | Asia Calling   |    1 |
|  1 | Sejarah Rumah Dengklok | 2018-05-01 22:40:47 | Saga           |    2 |
|  1 | Sejarah Rumah Dengklok | 2018-05-01 22:40:47 | Saga           |    3 |
|  3 | Berita Asia!           | 2018-05-01 22:52:15 | Asia Calling   |    4 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------+
```

What I expect?

I want to order playlist based on `sort` column and latest podcasts indicated by `published_at` column. Order using `sort` column is OK, but I can't order it by `published_at` date from podcasts.

Expected results:

```
+----+------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------+
| id | podcast_title          | published_at        | category_title | sort |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------+
|  4 | Asia Later!            | 2018-05-01 22:52:15 | Asia Calling   |    1 |
|  5 | Saga Terbaru           | 2018-05-01 22:40:47 | Saga           |    2 |
|  1 | Sejarah Rumah Dengklok | 2018-05-01 22:40:47 | Saga           |    3 |
|  3 | Berita Asia!           | 2018-05-01 22:52:15 | Asia Calling   |    4 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+----------------+------+
```

Can someone give me a clue how to do with it? Any link or source will be appreciated.

[Here is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3672ce/2/0) example full table structure and data from SQL Fiddle if you want to play with it.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouln't you have only 1 entry per category in category_sorts table?

Comment: As Jarek has already written you got duplicate result entrys because of multiple category entries. Further: Your primary sorting is the sort-value, the secondary is the date. What result do you expect?

Comment: Hello Jarek, I want to create playlist like this image: https://s31.postimg.cc/3keqwfjfv/3b623f74-497d-464c-b57a-bb4834029143.png. So, it's possible to have duplicate category_id. But, in the next same category will join with next podcast data (order by published_at DESC on podcasts).

Comment: Not enough information about the intended behaviour to say if the query is wrong or the schema is wrong - voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need multiple categories see my comment under your post but if you want to allow multiple categories as the examples seem to imply try the sql below. The only change is it groups by category_id so you don't get duplicates:

```
SELECT
        p.id, p.title AS podcast_title, p.published_at, 
        c.title AS category_title,
        cs.sort
    FROM podcasts as p
    INNER JOIN categories as c ON c.id = p.category_id
    INNER JOIN category_sorts AS cs on cs.category_id = c.id
    GROUP BY cs.category_id
    ORDER BY cs.sort ASC, p.published_at DESC
```

or actually to make it more bulletproof introduce aggregate `min(cs.sort) as sorting_order` so the order is always picked correctly and use in `ORDER` clause:

```
SELECT
        p.id, p.title AS podcast_title, p.published_at, 
        c.title AS category_title,
        min(cs.sort) as sorting_order
    FROM podcasts as p
    INNER JOIN categories as c ON c.id = p.category_id
    INNER JOIN category_sorts AS cs on cs.category_id = c.id
    GROUP BY cs.category_id
    ORDER BY sorting_order ASC, p.published_at DESC
```

But if you want to keep the category duplicates and get rid of podcast duplicates then:

```
SELECT
        p.id, p.title AS podcast_title, p.published_at, 
        c.title AS category_title,
        cs.sort
    FROM podcasts as p
    INNER JOIN categories as c ON c.id = p.category_id
    INNER JOIN category_sorts AS cs on cs.category_id = c.id
    GROUP BY p.id
    ORDER BY cs.sort ASC, p.published_at DESC
```

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3672ce/22

Comment: Thank you.

But I want to keep duplicate categories, but remove duplicate podcasts. :D